# Partial mock of a class with private constructor

Tags: .net, vb.net, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I am trying to write some unit tests on a class that looks like this, using Moq :

```
Public Interface IAwesomeInterface
    Function GetThis() As Integer
    Function GetThisAndThat(ByVal that As Integer) As Integer
End Interface


Public Class MyAwesomeClass
    Implements IAwesomeInterface

    Dim _this As Integer

    ''' <summary>
    ''' injection constructor
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub New(ByVal this As Integer)
        Me._this = this
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' default factory method
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared Function Create() As IAwesomeInterface
        Return New MyAwesomeClass(42)
    End Function

    Public Overridable Function GetThis() As Integer Implements IAwesomeInterface.GetThis
        Return _this
    End Function

    Public Function GetThisAndThat(ByVal that As Integer) As Integer Implements IAwesomeInterface.GetThisAndThat
        Return GetThis() + that
    End Function
End Class
```

- the parameterized constructor is private or internal
- one of the two methods relies on the result of the other

I want to check that when `GetThisOrThat` is called with a value, it actually calls GetThis. But I also want to mock `GetThis` so that it returns a specific well-known value.

To me this is an example of Partial Mocking, where we create a Mock based on a class, passing the parameters for the constructor. The problem here is that there is no public constructor, and therefore, Moq can not call it... 
I tried using the Accessors generated by Visual Studio for MSTest, and use those accessors for the mocking, and this is what I came up with :

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub GetThisAndThat_calls_GetThis()
    'Arrange
    Dim dummyAwesome = New Mock(Of MyAwesomeClass_Accessor)(56)
    dummyAwesome.CallBase = True

    dummyAwesome.Setup(Function(c) c.GetThis()).Returns(99)

    'Act
    Dim thisAndThat = dummyAwesome.Object.GetThisAndThat(1)

    'Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(100, thisAndThat)' Expected:<100>. Actual:<57>. 

    dummyAwesome.Verify(Function(d) d.GetThis, Times.Once, "GetThisAndThat should call GetThis")

End Sub
```

... but this fails. When executing the test, the GetThis returns 56 instead of 99.

Am I doing anything wrong ? 
In the other questions I read, I did not see a mention of this kind of scenario.

**UPDATE : based on answer by Tim Long**

I added this to the `AssemblyInfo.vb` of the assembly I am testing :

```
<Assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")>
```

(without including the PublicKey, i.e. not like specified in the documentation : http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart in *Advanced Features*)

And made the constructor `Friend` (=`internal`) instead of `Private`.
I can now use the `internal` constructor directly instead of using the MSTests `Accessor`s :

```
<TestClass()>
Public Class MyAwesomeTest

    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub GetThisAndThat_calls_GetThis()
        'Arrange
        Dim dummyAwesome = New Mock(Of MyAwesomeClass)(56)
        dummyAwesome.CallBase = True

        dummyAwesome.Setup(Function(c) c.GetThis()).Returns(99)

        'Act
        Dim thisAndThat = dummyAwesome.Object.GetThisAndThat(1)

        'Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(100, thisAndThat)

        dummyAwesome.Verify(Function(d) d.GetThis, Times.Once, "GetThisAndThat should call GetThis")

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your constructor Internal instead of private and then use an `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute to designate your unit tests as a 'friend assembly'.

Or, it might be worth looking at [Moles isolation framework](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) (MS Research)

Comment: I had tried marking the constructor as `internal` (i.e.`Friend`) and setting InternalsVisibleTo according to the documentation of Moq (i.e. DynamicProxyGenAssembly2 with `PublicKey`) and it failed with the error `System.NotSupportedException: Parent does not have a default constructor. The default constructor must be explicitly defined.`. Not including the PublicKey wroks as you say, though ... so thank you !